# Html Agility Pack get span class name in html

Tags: asp.net, html-agility-pack

I can get the company-employee-insights-item sections; however when I try to pull the class name for the specific span in graph-stats, it always returns employee-decrease. There are multiple sections on the page with the same section name (in a top down list format), as in the example below.

I need to pull the class name from the span in graph-stats. In some cases its employee-decrease or employee-increase.

I also need the Car Center text, this is why I am starting with company-employee-insights-item.

Can't figure our the best way to isolate the current span in the item For Each.  This is what I have so far; but every time it returns employee-decrease.

```
Dim ndes As Array = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'company-employee-insights-item')]").ToArray

    Dim result As String = String.Empty
                For Each item As HtmlNode In ndes

                    Dim nde As HtmlNode = item.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class,'graph-stats')]/span")

                    Dim s As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.OuterHtml.Trim)
                    result = result & s & " " & nde.Attributes(0).Value & "<br/>"

                Next
```

Here is a sample of the html with two sections of which there could be X sections on the page.

```
<section class="company-employee-insights-item">
            <dl>
              <dt>
                Car Center
                <span class="employee-counter">
                  (203)
                </span>
              </dt>
              <dd class="graph-stats">
                  <span class="employee-decrease">
                    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="caret-filled-down-icon"><svg></path></svg></li-icon>
                    3%
                  </span>
              </dd>
            </dl>
</section>

<section class="company-employee-insights-item">
            <dl>
              <dt>
                Truck Center
                <span class="employee-counter">
                  (203)
                </span>
              </dt>
              <dd class="graph-stats">
                  <span class="employee-increase">
                    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="caret-filled-down-icon"><svg></path></svg></li-icon>
                    3%
                  </span>
              </dd>
            </dl>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the wanted node can be described by always having a `<dd>` with a `class` value `graph-stats`, and a child `<span>` with a `class` value ***starting with*** `employee-`, so this works:

```
Dim document = New HtmlDocument
Dim xpath = "//dd[@class='graph-stats']/span[starts-with(@class, 'employee-')]"
document.LoadHtml(html)
For Each dd In document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)
    Console.WriteLine(dd.Attributes("class").Value)
Next
```

Comment: that is pulling all spans in the page, not the one in the item htmlnode.

Comment: I also need the Car Center text, this is why I am starting with company-employee-insights-item.

Comment: It's only pulling the **two** `<span>`s for me - even added an extra one using your example above.

Comment: I need the text before the graph-stats as well.

Comment: You should update the question to specify **exactly** what you need. Besides the text in the `<dt>`, there is also text in it's child `<span>` node.